# When we don't need a primary key for our table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

Will it ever happen that we design a table that doesn't need a primary key?

Comment: When you have only one row in table

Comment: @Shakti @EBAG, this is true, but 1) When does this ever happen? and, 2) It would be bad practice to limit your data to always having one row.  Better to design the database with the future in mind.  I'm sure you were semi-joking, but if the question is legitimate, then EBAG needs to know that even with only one row, no primary key is a bad idea.

Comment: @rockerest - when you want to have a table that represents various configuration options. You want to use different columns so that appropriate data types are used for each option (e.g. if you want a retries value for something, it's stored as an int). In that case, you want to ensure that there is only ever one row. Of course, in that case, the ideal (theoretical) primary key would be one with no columns, but I'm not aware of any SQL product that would allow you to declare it.

Comment: @Damien the scenario you outlined is true, but I've always felt that storing things that are guaranteed to be one row (like configuration or settings information) is a bastardization of a relational database.  Why create a table and generate overhead pulling the single record from that table when you could just store the information somewhere else?

Comment: @Shakti, A table that is constrained to have only one row by definition DOES have a key - the key is empty (an empty set of attributes). It's just that you can't specify that directly with SQL's PRIMARY KEY constraint. PRIMARY KEY != primary key :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## No.

The primary key does a lot of stuff behind-the-scenes, even if your application never uses it.

For example: [clustering](http://blogs.oracle.com/carriergrademysql/entry/mysql_cluster_basics_why_using) improves efficiency (because [heap tables](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1254) are a mess).

Not to mention, if ANYONE ever has to do something on your table that requires pulling a specific row and you don't have a primary key, you are the bad guy.

Answer (score 10):

## Yes.

If you have a table that will always be fetched completely, and is being referred-to by zero other tables, such as some kind of standalone settings or configuration table, then there is no point having a primary key, and the argument could be made by some that adding a PK in this situation would be a deception of the normal use of such a table.

It is *rare*, and probably when it is most often done it is done *wrongly*, but they do exist, and such instances can be valid.

Comment: Why would you want duplicate rows in such a table? When you say you never want to "fetch" individual rows does that mean you never want to update them and you would replace every row for every change to the data? Or do you mean the data is read only?

Comment: @dportas: everything you said.  ``unique`` is a way of preventing duplicate rows. Not having a PK is a way to indicate that this table should never be referred-to from another table.  The most common use case for this (and in general, keyless tables are very uncommon) is the classic single-record settings table.  I don't think it is _good_ to omit defining a PK, but it is wrong to mandate that every table must have one.  Were this so, we would not have the choice.

Comment: @crjh: Agreed that a "primary" key is always superfluous. My interpretation of your answer was that you meant "no key at all". If you meant: "a table ought to have at least one candidate key, one of which may or may not be called a primary one" then I agree. A table constrained to have one row is not an exception because it implicitly does have a (empty) key.

Comment: @dportas: sure, I think we're on the same page here.

Answer (score 3):

## Depends.

What is primary key / unique key?

> In relational database design, a unique key can uniquely identify each row in a table, and is closely related to the Superkey concept. A unique key comprises a single column or a set of columns. No two distinct rows in a table can have the same value (or combination of values) in those columns if NULL values are not used. Depending on its design, a table may have arbitrarily many unique keys but at most one primary key.

So, when you don't have to differentiate (uniquely identify) each row,
you don't have to use primary key

For example, a big table for logs,
without using primary key, you can have fairly smaller size of data and faster for insertion

Comment: ...but much slower for retrieval.  Back to the discussion about clustered versus heaped tables.  If there's no primary key, retrieving anything from the table will take much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key not mandatory but it is not a good practice to create tables without primary key. DBMS creates auto-index on PK, but you can make a column unique and index it, e.g. `user_name` column in `users` table are usually made unique and indexed, so you may choose to skip PK here. But it is *still a bad idea* because PK can be used as foreign key for referential integrity.

In general, you should **almost always** have PK in a table unless you have very strong reason to justify not having a PK.

Link tables (in many to many relationship) may not have a primary key. But, I personally like to have PK in those tables as well.

Comment: I also add a PK to my many-to-many tables.  Not sure why, but I feel "safer" with them there :)

Comment: Many-to-many tables should have a primary key as well! Not because it feels safer, but to have a fast way to identify records. Just as you need it in (almost) all other tables, as described in the other answers.